# Speech recognition in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I searched for about 3 days for a library or something for speech recognition via python 3 .. i found all libraries Outdated , Is their any way to do it ? , i'm Working on Windows 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you still need it or someone else would come across this question, I recently found this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

It uses Google Speech Recognition API.

Tested it on my MacBook OS X 10.8.5 / Python 3.4 - works fine when processing input from the microphone, supports different languages.

Keep in mind for some tasks it may require you to install additional modules, here's a quote from its requirements:

> The first software requirement is Python 3.3 or better. This is
>   required to use the library.
>
> Additionally, it must be 32-bit Python if you are using the included
>   PyAudio binaries. It is also technically possible though inconvenient
>   to compile PyAudio for 64-bit Python.
>
> If you want to use the Microphone class (necessary for recording from
>   microphone input), PyAudio is also necessary. If not installed, the
>   library will still work, but Microphone will be undefined.
>
> The official PyAudio builds seem to be broken on Windows. As a result,
>   in the installers folder you will find unofficial builds for Windows
>   that actually work. Run installers/PyAudio-0.2.7.win32-py3.3.exe for
>   Python 3.3 and PyAudio-0.2.7.win32-py3.4.exe for Python 3.4.
>
> A FLAC encoder is required to encode the audio data to send to the
>   API. If using Windows or Linux, the encoder is already bundled with
>   this library. Otherwise, ensure that you have the flac command line
>   tool, which is often available through one's system package manager.